# plot vector of text matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

The following figure represent an iteration of a for loop in real time simulation

[image]

each side (20 circles) is a vector of events such that:

```
events=zeros(1,20);
time=zeros(1,20);
for i=1:N
    if 'something'
        events(k)=value;
        time(k)=i*dt;
    end
end
```

when every iteration `events(k)` updates ( and a colored circle is ploted) I want to plot `time(k)` next to it as a text, how can this be obtained

Comment: Your code doesn't have the spatial locations of where the circles are.  Can you include that with your code?  If you do that, all you have to do is use the `text` function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html

Comment: but the text command does the job, thanks